# jquery slider responsive problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-slides

I am a beginner with jQuery and I was trying to make an slider responsive and is working but I have some bugs that I want to fix, first of all when is passing to the next picture some times it just turn white and it does not working any more, and second some times it start to go faster and faster.

Any suggestions?

```
.mascara
{ width: 100%; height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.carrusel{ position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

 .carrusel li{ width:25%; height: 100%; float: left; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover; }

<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var cantidadFotos = $('.carrusel li').size();

var incremento =  $('.mascara').width();
var limite = (cantidadFotos-1) * incremento;
var velocidad = 550;

$('.carrusel').css('width', (cantidadFotos*100)+"%");
$('.carrusel li').css('width', incremento+"px");

var posX = 0;

 resize();

function resize()
{
 $(window).resize(function () {
    incremento =  $('.mascara').width();
    $('.carrusel li').css('width', incremento+"px");
    posX = -(incremento * imagenes);
    $('.carrusel').css('left', posX+"px");
 });

setInterval(function(){ nextFoto(); }, 3000);}
var imagenes = 0;
function nextFoto(){

    imagenes++;
    posX+= -incremento;

    if (posX<-limite){
        posX=0;
        imagenes = 0;
        $('.carrusel').css({ left: posX });
        }
   $('.carrusel').animate({ left: posX},350);
    // $('.carrusel').css({ left: posX});
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi can you create a fiddle? also try to edit you question in your post and not in comment, so we can read your code well. you can make fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mgHn4/ the code is here!!! i need help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the blank page when sliding, change to this:

In `.carrusel`

Change:

```
position: relative;
```

To:

```
position: absolute;
```

And to make it faster, change:

```
setInterval(function () {
        nextFoto();
    }, 3000);
```

To

```
setInterval(function () {
        nextFoto();
    }, 1000);
```

Change according to your needs to make it faster!

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgHn4/2/)**